# ESP32 Espressif ESP32_DevKitC_V4 in platformio: flash issues

Tags: esp32, flash, espressif, platformio

I am using the Espressif ESP32_DevKitC_V4 with platformio, and i cannot flash the board. I read about the various "button dance" procedures, and [the ES32-WROVER and the ESP32-WROVER-B seem to behave differently as well](https://github.com/espressif/esptool/issues/226).

From the 80 tries of doing the "button dance" i got it one time to work. Are there any other options on how to flash the board with platformio without attaching a 100nF capacitor from EN to GND?

Here is the output when trying to flash

```
Auto-detected: /dev/ttyUSB0
Uploading .pio/build/ESP32/firmware.bin
esptool.py v3.0
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Connecting........_
Chip is ESP32-D0WD (revision 1)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: 4c:11:ae:6c:c8:b4
Uploading stub...

A fatal error occurred: Invalid head of packet (0x65)
*** [upload] Error 2  ========== 

[FAILED] Took 9.83 seconds ==========================
    The terminal process "platformio 'run', '--target', 'upload'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

These are the settings in the platformio.ini file:

```
[env:ESP32]
platform = espressif32
framework = espidf
board = esp32dev
board_build.flash_mode = dio
```

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Reduce the programming baud rate?

Comment: A genius solved this problem by attaching a 100nF capacitor from EN to GND.